# How to use basic authorization in PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, authorization

I am having problem with PHP curl request with basic authorization.

Here is the command line curl:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/product+xml" "https://{id}:{api_key}@api.domain.com/products?limit=1&offset=0"
```

I have tried by setting curl header in following ways but it's not working

```
Authorization: Basic id:api_key
or 
Authorization: Basic {id}:{api_key}
```

I get the response "authentication parameter in the request are missing or invalid" but I have used proper id and api_key which is working in command line curl (I tested)

Please help me.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
$username='ABC';
$password='XYZ';
$URL='<URL>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Nice one! I had `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, 'CURLAUTH_BASIC');` but that wasn't working. Used your `CURLAUTH_ANY` and we're golden!

Comment: I also was able to remove the `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` line and have it work properly.

Comment: @JoshPinter, you were using the string `'CURLAUTH_BASIC'` instead of the constant `CURLAUTH_BASIC`

Comment: This worked for me
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
        [
         "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($this->username.":".$this->password),
        ]);`

Comment: do i still need to secure my php file when i use 'CURLOPT_USERPWD` so hackers won't know the username and password?

Comment: Shouldn't curl_getinfo() come after curl_exec()?

Comment: It works for me except when I click on a link on the result page. How can I make another call to this script on clicking a link on the result page?

Answer (score 9):

Can you try this,

```
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 ...
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
 ...
```

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: This actually worked for me instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");`

Comment: @HarishPrasanna, it's the same thing...

Answer (score 7):

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($username.':'.$password),
);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Comment: When answering a six year old question with three existing answers it is important to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation.

Comment: @JasonAller I'd tested all of them but wasn't working. There is a comment like my answer but I think this solution must be an answer.

Comment: @Danoosh your code is redundant. You manually construct the AUTH header specifying you want Basic and base64-encoding the user/pwd + instruct cURL to itself create an AUTH header using Basic auth, but didn't provide cURL any user/pwd to use, so it can't do it. Choose only 1 method - the 2nd one - why manully implement the encoding when cURL can do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple Way To Pass Header

```
function get_data($url) {

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
$username = 'c4f727b9646045e58508b20ac08229e6';        // Put Username 
$password = '';                                        // Put Password
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");    // Add This Line
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$url = "https://storage.scrapinghub.com/items/397187/2/127";
$data = get_data($url);
echo '<pre>';`print_r($data_json);`die;    // For Print Value
```

[Check My JSON Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRlSC.jpg)