# Construct URL with Authorization header for REST API call

Tags: php, html, rest

I have to construct URL for a rest api delete call in php. For it I need to generate a url dynamically for each of the items in a list. The url is of the form localhost/tasks/delete/task_id where task_id is the variable for each item,
 I also need to put an authorization header in the url which would contain api key. I have to anchor this url to a link in html.

I can append the task_id but I couldn't find a way to  include the header. Please provide in code/pseudo code how to do this.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20064360/165043

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov I have actually inplemented post, get calls using curl but now I am trying to make a rest call through url only.

Comment: You can't include header in url-only call

Comment: if you want a user from browser to access the api, then you can try this: `user:password@localhost/tasks/delete/task_id`

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov Thanks How can I call delete functionality then on click of a link?

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov can i call i php script that does this like clicking an image <img src="photo/suppc.png" width="295" height="36" onclick="supcont.php" target="fenetreA" /> but my problem is how will i pass task id to the php script ?

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov So, I need to generate url appended by task id after passing the task id to php script , right ? Since, you have a lot of experience in php could you please help me with some code ? Thanks.