# BigCommerce API Call - Get Orders

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce

I'm trying to do a simple API call in BigCommerce.
I got some info from these links:

[Get a Count of Orders](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#get-a-count-of-orders)

[BigCommerce API Quickstarts](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-quickstarts/blob/master/curl/orders_examples.md)

I've tried orders.json and orders/count, but I do not get any response.
I must be missing something simple. Do I have to echo the response somehow?

Here is my code.

```
<?php

curl --request GET \
  -u "username:key" \
  https://store.com/api/v2/orders/count;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a reply from BigCommerce and it was no help.

I figured this out with the help of "[how to use basic authorization in php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl)", "[JSON to PHP Using json_decode](http://dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php)", and "[JSON](http://json.org)".

I ran this code, in a .php file, on a GoDaddy hosted server running PHP 5.6.22 and curl 7.36.0.

```
<?php

$username = "Username";
$password = "API Token";
$URL = "https://store.com/api/v2/orders/count.json";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //Timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //Get status code

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($response);

echo "Count = " . $result->count; //Total orders
echo "<br />" . $result->statuses[8]->name . " = " . $result->statuses[8]->count; //Shipped orders

?>
```