# How to authorize when sending the API key using CURL?

Tags: php, curl

Getting 401 Unauthorized HTTP code response when i am sending request with API KEY using CURL in PHP.

I tried with different solution but still i am getting same error.

Can you any one help on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl)

Comment: How are you sending the request right now?

Comment: Please see the below for more details.
<?php
$url  =  'https://hostname/storage/v1/promotion-campaigns/b/?apikey=key';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','','Authorization: Basic [key]'));        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'key');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

I am sending the request like above