# use Curl to access API with username and password in PHP

Tags: php, json, url, zendesk-api

This is the sample code but using Curl on cmd :

```
curl https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats -u {username}:{password}
```

How do I query it in PHP?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

Comment: @ivor this API is on post or get method? I think it is post, right?

Comment: hmm.. i need to get the json of this link...

Comment: @ivor but which kind of method this API is using? post or get bro!

Comment: @duongkhang Get method bro...

Comment: @ivor can you give me test username and password?

Comment: @duongkhang sorry bro but this one is controversial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe answered on [How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl)
so try from that:

```
<?php
$username='username';
$password='pass';
$URL='https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
```

to print or show the json use:

```
$obj = json_decode($result);
print $obj->{'user'}; 
echo $obj->{'message'};
```