# Unable to Curl-php into same server Electrum

Tags: php, curl

NOTE: 
[How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl) 
Does not work for me.

Trying to Curl into Electrum, but it looks like my access is denied. Electrum is on the same server as the php script. I have purposefully left out any command for the wallet for simplification purpose. Focusing on connecting first.

When trying to CURL in terminal

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"addrequest","params":{"amount":"3.14","memo":"test"}}' http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:7777
```

Error Message

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7777: Connection refused
```

EDIT: The above CURL Command in Terminal now works

PHP

```
$password = 'root';         
$username = 'password';
$URL='http://127.0.0.1';   //Curl into own machine local ip is needed.
$port = 7777;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$result=curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<br>";
var_dump($result);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($status_code);
```

Below is my error

> Error:
>
> bool(false)
>
> int(0)

Below are my netstats. Port is open and listening.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

`PHP7, PHP-CURL & CURL` are installed on linux Fedora 27. Webserver type `Apache 2.4` `Electrum 3.1.2`

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1 7777
```

Returns:

```
Rebuilt URL to: 127.0.0.1/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 04 Apr 2018 18:22:14 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Fedora)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 

/*index.php code*/

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Rebuilt URL to: 7777/
*   Trying 0.0.30.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 0.0.30.97: Invalid argument
* Closing connection 1
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Comment: Try enabling curl verbose output and see if that gives you a clue: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: There is no ssl

Comment: Leave PHP aside for now, can you get it to work with curl command line?

Comment: [root@fedora-e ~]# curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"addrequest","params":{"amount":"3.14","memo":"test"}}' http://username:password@127.0.0.1:7777
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7777: Connection refused

Comment: what is your Electrum **version** ?

Comment: do `curl -v 127.0.0.1 7777` it provides verbose mode. It looks that there is a listener, but, that doesn't  ensure you get a reply. Check the Electrum backend.

Comment: Electrum Version 3.1.2

Comment: curl -v 127.0.0.1 7777 returns: view edit

Comment: looks to me like Electrum was designed by idiots - the api doesn't support encryption, listens to connections from anywhere (not only 127.0.0.1), and uses HTTP Basic Auth, meaning the username/password is sent in plain text on every api request, for any hacker listening in on the network (Wireshark?), a horribly insecure setup...

Comment: You have password and username switched around. `$password = 'root';` Shouldn't the user name be `root`? This might just be a typo because you removed the sensitive data, but if you have them mixed up, this might explain your problem :-)

Comment: I know I'm just throwing in things that you have probably tried and considered before, but I want to make sure it's nothing trivial that got overlooked. Have you tried setting the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option? What is the value of `curl_errno($ch)` (as it doesn't seem to be `0`)? What happens if you dump the whole `curl_getinfo($ch)` (without specifying an option)?

Comment: Please make sure you have port 7777 available.

Comment: The remote server might be unfriendly to automation looking user agents. Try setting the user agent header to something generic, like Google's user agent.

Comment: What does `curl -v 127.0.0.1:7777` output? The current variant (with a space) is useless

Answer (score 0):

You need another curl option set:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

So the final sequence would be:

```
$password = 'root';
$username = 'password';
$URL='http://127.0.0.1';   //Curl into own machine local ip is needed.
$port = 7777;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");


$result=curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<br>";
var_dump($result);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($status_code);
```

Comment: Howdy, have tried this and CURLAUTH_ANY, no success