# PHP not curling into own server

Tags: php, php-curl

NOTE: 
[How to use basic authorization in PHP curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064271/how-to-use-basic-authorization-in-php-curl) 
Does not work for me.

```
$password = 'root';         
$username = 'password';
$URL='http://127.0.0.1';   //Curl into own machine local ip is needed.
$port = 7777;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }

$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<br>";
var_dump($result);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($status_code);
```

Below is my error

> Error:
>
> bool(false)
>
> int(0)

Below are my netstats. Port is open and listening.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

`PHP7, PHP-CURL & CURL` are installed on linux Fedora 27. Webserver type `Apache 2.4`

Trying to Curl into Electrum

Comment: I don't think you can SSH using CURL lib...

Comment: sshd in general will not 'speak' https, so I am not sure what you are attempting to achieve here.

Comment: Thank you did not know. Changed it back to original port trying to connect to 7777. If this is a ssh port how can I change it to a http port?

Comment: The web server listens on port `80` (the default HTTP port). You are trying to connect to port `22` where `sshd` listens but `sshd` doesn't understand HTTP (or HTTPS) and `curl` doesn't know the SSH protocol. Why do you attempt to connect to `localhost:22`?

Comment: Do you have an HTTP server listening on port `7777`? It is not listed in the dump of `netstat` you posted.

Comment: You need to run a webserver to listen on port `7777` and handle your curl request

Comment: With regards to listen on port 7777. I have tried the command 'Listen 7777' but a 'command not found' was returned

Comment: Tried it where? If you don't *already* have a webserver listening on port 7777, where has that number come from?

Comment: Port 7777 will appear on netstat after i Daemon Start the program I am trying to curl to. However, the port 7777 does not stay on Listen.

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you are trying to do. Do you have another program that listens on port 7777? Which protocol does it use? Is it third party or can you change it?

Comment: Electrum wallet. It used 'HTTP basic auth'