# Download and store remote password protected file with PHP

Tags: php, download, password-protection, libssh2

When I type into any browser's address bar :
https://username:password@www.example.com/Protected/Export/MyFile.zip, 
the file gets downloaded normally.

Now I'm trying to do the same with PHP : connect to the remote password-protected file and download it into a local directory (like ./downloads/).

I've tried several ways with PHP (ssh2_connect(), copy(), fopen(), ...) but none were successful.

```php
$originalConnectionTimeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3); // reduces waiting time

$connection = ssh2_connect("www.example.com");

// use $connection to download the file

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $originalConnectionTimeout);
if($connection !== false) ssh2_disconnect($connection);
```

Output :
"Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to www.example.com on port 22 [..]"

How can I download this file with PHP and store it on a local directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When accessing an url like

```
https://username:password@www.example.com/Protected/Export/MyFile.zip
```

you're using [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which sends the `Authorization` HTTP header. This has nothing to do with `ssh`, hence you cannot use `ssh2_connect()`.

To access this with php, you could use curl:

```php
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$url = 'https://www.example.com/Protected/Export/MyFile.zip';

$curl = curl_init();
// Define which url you want to access
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Add authorization header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ':' . $password);

// Allow curl to negotiate auth method (may be required, depending on server)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

// Get response and possible errors
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Save file
$file = fopen('/path/to/file.zip', "w+");
fputs($file, $reponse);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: With correct credentials and url, I get a "401 Unauthorized" error : 
Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.xxxxxx.tld Port 80

Comment: @Frank1999 Could you try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$password");` instead of the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER ...)` line? Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064360/4946451)

Comment: And if that still does not work, try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);`, too. This will allow curl to negotiate which auth way works instead of just using Basic Auth.

Comment: Just tried CURLOPT_USERPWD, but still unauthorized. Also please note that $ch should be $curl (small copy-paste issue). I'll keep on trying with next suggestion (curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);).

Comment: Adding curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: there is an error in curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ':' . $password); //CHANGE VARIABLE NAME TO $curl

Answer (score 1):

This is not SSH protocol. It may be something like [Apache HTTP Authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html). You can follow and try this guide: [HTTP authentication with PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)